# Edit Text to set Repeating Alarm

Tags: android, android-edittext, alarmmanager

I am trying to set an alarm to repeat in minutes with an edit text,but it seems to just work when it wants to.

```
    public void startAlert(View view) {
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        try {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        pendingintrent = PendingIntent.getService(this.getApplicationContext(),
                12345, myIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                i * 60 * 60 , pendingintrent);
         } catch (Exception e) {}

        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " minutes",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The time interval value in `setRepeating()` method is in millisecond format. So you need to change your `setRepeating()` method's line as below,

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
        i * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingintrent);
```